# File Server, Unidad compartida se llena automaticamente

Tags: windows, servidor

Les comparto mi duda y problema en busca de que alguien pueda ayudarme

Tengo un File Server en Server 2010, todo estaba trabajando bien hasta hace unos dias donde comenzo a fallar, y es que la unidad D que es la que tengo compartida comenzo a disminuir su espacio, ejemplo de 440GB me dice que estoy al 99% de capacidad aunque el espacio asignado es de 550GB, igual otras carpetas dentro de la unidad D me dicen lo mismo, 50GB con 99% de espacio en uso, capacidad real 60gb

He buscado y no logro dar con la solucion, ha a lguien le ha pasado esto mismo? saben que podria ser?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Cuando hablas de "el espacio asignado es 550 GB" y "de 440 GB me dice que estoy al 99%". ¿Dónde consultas esos datos?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo el uso de alguna herramienta del tipo windirstat para ver lo que realmente tienes (https://windirstat.net/). Recuerda ejecutarla como administrador.
Intenta asociar capturas de pantalla a las preguntas para facilitar la comprensión.